# conditional where clause based on a stored procedure parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server 2005 stored proc that takes a parameter: `@includeClosedProjects`.

There's a `WHERE` clause that I want to control based on this param.

```
create proc sel_projects
(@incClosedRel int = 1)
as

SELECT projectId, projectName
FROM project
WHERE CompletionStatusCID NOT IN (34, 35) <-- controlled by @incClosedRel
```

I want to get all projects (exclude the where clause), when `@incClosedRel =1`. 
Otherwise, include the where clause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT projectId, projectName
FROM project
WHERE CompletionStatusCID NOT IN (34, 35) 
    Or @incClosedRel = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create proc yourproc
@value int
as

if @value = 1
begin
-- your select query
end
else
begin
--your other select query
end
```