# Stored procedure to call a different stored procedure based on parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I would like to create a stored procedure in Sql Server that calls one of a number of different stored procedures and chooses which one based on the parameter supplied to it, but I can't seem to get the choosing syntax right.

Currently attempting:

```
Begin
  Set nocount on;
  exec iif(param='individual', sp_FindIndividualRespondents, 
      iif(param='org', sp_FindOrgRespondents, sp_FindGroupRespondents))
End
```

This is currently telling me: Incorect syntax near 'param'.

I have looked here: [conditional where clause based on a stored procedure parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159528/conditional-where-clause-based-on-a-stored-procedure-parameter), but I can't work out how to change that code to suit my situation.

How do i provide a parameter to a stored procedure and then use it to choose and run a different stored procedure?

Comment: iif doesn't exist in SQL 2008, that is SQL 2012 only.

Comment: so is me using a 2012 client with a 2008 server causing the problem, do you think?

Comment: The 2008 server will not support it, but you can accomplish this with a CASE statement for your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @queryToRun NVARCHAR(128) = 'EXECUTE ';

   SELECT @queryToRun = @queryToRun + CASE
                                         WHEN param = 'individual'
                                            THEN 'sp_FindIndividualRespondents'
                                         WHEN param = 'org'
                                            THEN 'sp_FindOrgRespondents'
                                         ELSE 'sp_FindGroupRespondents'
                                      END

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @queryToRun;
END
```

---

If you do not need the dynamic sql, which it appears in this example you do not, you can simply check the value and run the appropriate stored procedures:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF param = 'individual'
      EXECUTE sp_findIndividualRespondents;
   ELSE IF param = 'org'
      EXECUTE sp_FindOrgRespondents;
   ELSE
      EXECUTE sp_FindGroupRespondents;
END
```

Comment: a li'l confused at your Execute line.  my sp creation syntax seems a bit different.  the template didn't indicate a need for 'declare' at the beginning of the params, for instance.  Should your suggestion go between the Begin and End in the SP?

Comment: @mcalex The first option is storing the name of the sproc in a variable to execute at the end.  Since you are not requiring the dynamic sql, you should be find to just implement the bottom option with the `IF ELSE...` syntax.

Comment: @mcalex Yes, I've added the `BEGIN...END` around my answer to be more clear for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN 
 IF param = "individual" 
   EXEC Sp_findindividualrespondents; 

 IF param = "org" 
   EXEC Sp_findorgrespondents; 

 IF param = "Nothing" 
   EXEC Sp_findgrouprespondents; 
END
```

OR

```
BEGIN 
 IF param = "individual" 
   EXEC Sp_findindividualrespondents; 
 ELSE IF param = "org" 
   EXEC Sp_findorgrespondents; 
 ELSE 
   EXEC Sp_findgrouprespondents; 
END
```