# Call specific stored procedure based on the parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have stored procedures:

1. `[SP_Fetch_Budget_Data_ADF]`
2. `SP_Fetch_Data_ADF`

Both these stored procedures have the same parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DW].[SP_Fetch_Budget_Data_ADF]
    @Date varchar(10), 
    @Entity varchar (12), 
    @Scenario varchar(10)
```

Parameters are passed from other tool. My goal is to write a 3rd stored procedure where I pass the parameter `@Scenario varchar(10)` (same parameter as for both stored procedures as shown above, so this parameter is supposed to be passed to all 3 stored procedures).

If `@Scenario` = "actual" then execute `SP_Fetch_Data_ADF` else execute `SP_Fetch_Budget_Data_ADF`.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081347/stored-procedure-to-call-a-different-stored-procedure-based-on-parameter) but I did not understand how to pass the parameter.

**UPDATE**

Below is my code, but I get this error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'SP_Fetch_Budget_Data_ADF'

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DW].[SP_EXECUTE_ADF] 
    @Scenario varchar(10)  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
   
    DECLARE @queryToRun NVARCHAR(128) = 'EXECUTE ';

    SELECT @queryToRun = @queryToRun + CASE
                                         WHEN @Scenario  = 'actual'
                                            THEN 'DW.SP_Fetch_Data_ADF'
                                         ELSE 'DW.SP_Fetch_Budget_Data_ADF'
                                      END

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @queryToRun;
END
```

Comment: You can easily create the query you want in raw text and run it with the `EXECUTE sp_executesql @yourQuery;`, Add the parameters in the same query

Comment: could you please provide a sample code, I did not fully understand

Comment: [This link](https://www.kodyaz.com/articles/tsql-sp_executesql-with-output-parameters.aspx) may help you

Comment: **Note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an IF statement to choose which procedure to call (and get rid of the `sp_` prefix; stored procedures shouldn't have *any* prefix, let alone the special `sp_` prefix).  EG

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE DW.Fetch_Budget_Data_ADF
    @Date varchar(10), 
    @Entity varchar (12)
as
select 1 a
go
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE DW.Fetch_Data_ADF
    @Date varchar(10), 
    @Entity varchar (12)
as
select 2 a

go

CREATE PROCEDURE DW.EXECUTE_ADF
    @Date varchar(10), 
    @Entity varchar (12), 
    @Scenario varchar(10) 
as
begin
  if @Scenario = 'actual'
  begin
    exec Fetch_Data_ADF @Date, @Entity
  end
  else
  begin
    exec Fetch_Budget_Data_ADF @Date, @Entity
  end

end
```

Comment: I still get same error `Could not find stored procedure 'SP_Fetch_Budget_Data_ADF'`

Comment: @Greencolor - That's a different issue.  Possibly that SP doesn't exist (check the spelling, etc), perhaps there's are permissions issues so your user can't see the SP, or your connection isn't using the `DW` schema, in which case edit the `DW.EXECUTE_ADF` to specify the `DW` schema before the two SPs being called.

Comment: was spelling error, that took me 1h to notice. Thanks